# Issue with list of list in py yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I have this yaml im trying to load into python with yaml.safe_load(file) and everytime im getting

> yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping   in
> "../fdlmyamls/testHolder/myfile.yaml", line 12, column 9 expected
> , but found '-'   in "../fdlmyamls/testHolder/myfile.yaml",
> line 13, column 9

The file im trying to load is

```
myList:
  - Name: MyName
    Attributes:
      - Name: myInnerName
        - Context: some_context
          Description: ""
          Value:
            Trial:
              Description: some description
              ID: myId
              User: myUser
              Options:
                - Label: label1
                  Value: 1
                  Weight: 0.25
                - Label: label2
                  Value: 0
                  Weight: 0.75
```

but on the line starting with context im getting errors on the load. the pyyaml library returns this what i posted earlier, where as some other online validators gave me this:

A block sequence may not be used as an implicit map key at line 13, column 1 Implicit keys need to be on a single line at line 13, column 9 Implicit map keys need to be followed by map values at line 13,
column 9

Comment: That's not a valid YAML document. `Attributes` is a list; the first item is a dictionary. `Name` is the first key in the ditionary; the following line would need to be a new key, or outdented by two spaces if you want to introduce a new list item. If you have a hard time thinking about indentation, just use JSON instead (which happens to be valid YAML all by itself, and maybe makes it easier to reason about lists vs maps vs scalar values).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of Syntax Errors in your yaml.
I would suggest you to use JSON (.json files) instead, since it is easier to write and read manually but contains exactly the same data.

Import json like this: `import json`

You can load a json file to python like this:

```
filepath = 'myfile.json'
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

You can save Json to a file like this:

```
filepath = 'myfile.json'
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    data = json.dump(f)
```

Python to Json datatypes:

```
Python -> JSON
dict      Object
list      Array
tuple     Array
str       String
int       Number
float     Number
True      true
False     false
None      null
```

More about Json:

[Json docs](https://www.json.org/j),

[about the json Python library](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

[actual json Python library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)